# Cannot Assign Private Variable In Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, compile-error

I have an issue, I want to test this line of code:

```
if(compareAnIssue!=null){
```

The variable in my controller is:

```
private DataToCompare compareAnIssue ;
```

and the `DataToCompare` type is a public class in my controller that I use to compare some fields:

```
public class DataToCompare {
```

I am trying to do it like this:

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController();
ControllerName  controllerName = new ControllerName(sc);
controllerName.compareAnIssue = '';
```

The problem arrives in the last line, which throws this compile error:

> Line x, Column y
>   Variable is not visible: controllerName.compareAnIssue

How I can increase this line's coverage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't ordinarily "see" private members, but you can add [@TestVisible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) to allow the unit test to see the variable:

```
@TestVisible DataToCompare compareAnIssue;
```

Then, your unit test can do stuff with it:

```
controller.compareAnIssue = new ControllerName.DataToCompare();
```

Answer (score 5):

To access private variables, you can make use of TestVisible Annotation:

```
public class TestVisibleExample {
    // Private member variable
    @TestVisible private static Integer recordNumber = 1;

    // Private method
    @TestVisible private static void updateRecord(String name) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

---

```
@isTest
private class TestVisibleExampleTest {
    @isTest static void test1() {
        // Access private variable annotated with TestVisible
        Integer i = TestVisibleExample.recordNumber;
        System.assertEquals(1, i);

        // Access private method annotated with TestVisible
        TestVisibleExample.updateRecord('RecordName');
        // Perform some verification
    }
}
```

Code is from [this reference doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm), read [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testvisible.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to access a `private` class variable, `compareAnIssue`, outside of that class. `Private` variables are only accessible within the class they are declared in. There are two ways around this:

Make it public:

```
public DataToCompare compareAnIssue;
```

(Recommended) Keep it private, but use `@TestVisible` to allow access from test classes only.

```
@testVisible private DataToCompare compareAnIssue;
```

In either case, your test code can access it like your example above. (Although of course setting it to a String wouldn't work right, since it's an instance of DataToCompare)

Comment: Test class will not work as written as compareAnIssue is an instance of DataToCompare not a string

Comment: Thank you to replied me, i solved for the visibility but how i can cast my variable in the string? i received the same error problem about illegal assignment.